# Make FastAPI/sqlalchemy reuse filter for multiple queries which all uses the same filter at first

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

Say I have a table in a database

```
id | name | pet
---+------+----
1  |  foo   dog
1  |  bar   cat
2  |  foo   bird
```

Then I have an API where you can provide a list of `name` and one `id`, and it will return the pet for each `name` for the given id

I can get the data I expect

```
def get_pets(id_, list_of_names):
    PETS = []
    for name in list_of_names:
    
        query = select(TableModel.pet).filter(TableModel.id== id_).filter(TableModel.name=name)
        PETS.append(session.execute(query))
    return PETS
```

the issue is that the filter on `id` is being created for each query which is stupid i.e for each query the database has to filter for the same `id` and then extract the name.

Isn't there a way to optimize this, such that the database just can use the same first filter, and then search for the `name`?

Answer (score 1):

You can create generic function that will apply these filters to any query:

```
from typing import TypeVar
from sqlalchemy import select, Select
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str]

class PetModel(Base):
    __tablename__="pets"
    pet: Mapped[str]


T = TypeVar("T", bound=Base)

def apply_filters(st: Select[T], id_, name) -> Select[T]:
    return st.filter_by(id=id_).filter_by(name=name)


def get_pets(id_, list_of_names):
    PETS = []
    for name in list_of_names:
    
        query = apply_filters(select(PetModel.pet), id_, name)
        print(query)
        # PETS.append(session.execute(query))
    return PETS 


get_pets(1, ["Fluffy", "Bonnie"])
```

Output:

```
SELECT pets.pet 
FROM pets 
WHERE pets.id = :id_1 AND pets.name = :name_1

SELECT pets.pet 
FROM pets 
WHERE pets.id = :id_1 AND pets.name = :name_1
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to optimize query creation in this particular loop, you can create constant part of query once and create custom queries (with the filter by `name`) based on it:

```
def get_pets(id_, list_of_names):
    PETS = []
    query_base = select(TableModel.pet).filter(TableModel.id== id_)
    for name in list_of_names:
    
        query = query_base.filter(TableModel.name=name)
        PETS.append(session.execute(query))
    return PETS
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use an `IN` query and get all your pets in one database call?

```py
def get_pets(id_, list_of_names):
    query = (
        select(TableModel.pet)
        .filter(
            TableModel.id=id_,
            TableModel.name.in_(list_of_names),
        )
    )
    return session.scalars(query)
```